# Why does my code only respond to keystrokes twice?

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio

I'm writing an application in C# that checks for keystrokes to pause or play music via NAudio. I have a loop that looks for a keystroke in another form, but for some reason it does not break to pause the music and prevent another loop (which means it replays music) after two keystrokes. I have debugged using breakpoints and looked at autos to see if I'm assigning variables correctly, but for some reason it just simply does not execute any code after I press A once and S (the keystrokes in question) once.

Here is the code which looks for key triggers and assigns variables:

```
        private void Form2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Delay(100);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            stgiga.Class1.starting = true; //triggers music
            Class1.pressed = true; //indicates keypress to Form1
            Task.Delay(1000);
            Class1.pressed = false; //switches to false to stop looping
          

        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
   
            Class1.playing = false;  //stops music
            Class1.pressed = true; //indicates keypress to Form1
            Task.Delay(1000);
            Class1.pressed = false; //prevents looping
            var p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\REAPER (x64)\reaper.exe";  //unrelated
            p.Start();
        }
        }
```

Here is the loop which looks for changes in variables and responds appropriately:

```
            while (true)
        {

            if (stgiga.Class1.pressed == true & stgiga.Class1.playing == false)
            {
                output.Stop(); //Stop audio via. NAudio

               while(stgiga.Class1.starting == false ) //waits until starting = true to make playing = true so it doesn't loop through twice and play
                { 
                }    
                stgiga.Class1.playing = true;
            }
            if (stgiga.Class1.starting == true & stgiga.Class1.pressed == true)
            {
                main(); //Main is another loop that should play audio
                stgiga.Class1.starting = false;

            }
        }
```

Lastly, this is what's supposed to break the main() loop but fails after two keystrokes:

```
   if (stgiga.Class1.playing == false)
            {
                output.Stop();
                break;
            }
```

Thank you.

Comment: you know your `Task.Delay(...)` will have no effect if it isn't awaited

Comment: You'd better complete the code. For example, what is `class1`? Why use a loop to do it. I see from your code that you can even achieve something similar using the timer control.

Comment: Class1 contains variables that can be used across forms to trigger code and pass information. I'm using a loop because it needs to be checked constantly as a key could be pressed at any moment. I know now there are better ways to do this but at the time I wrote this, it was the best method I could think of to handle that. What do you mean by "I see from your code that you can even achieve something similar using the timer control" ?

Comment: [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0) Use the timer control to write an event that checks the state every s, as an alternative to your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Where to begin....Don't make infinite loops?

Likely, your loop is in the UI thread, so of course it stops getting input. But, maybe you have that in another thread.

Even in another thread, it won't serve you well. Your CPU usage will hit 100%. You should never just loop as fast as you can checking a variable for a few reason.  First, the optimizer might just optimize out the check, since nothing inside the loop can change the value. But, also, just horribly runs your thread and makes it unable to be used for anything else.

`Task.Delay` schedules a task that will complete after the given time. But, you don't actually WAIT for that task to complete.

You need to fire some kind of event when changes happen, and then respond to those events. Don't loop on something looking for changes.

To use events, you would declare the event handler:

`public event EventHandler MusicStarting`;

you would then register to handle that event:

```
    MusicStarting += handleMusicStaring;


    static void handleMusicStaring(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do what you want when music starts here.
    }
```

and, of course, you need to trigger the event when you start the music:

```
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
    {
        MusicStarting?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty)
    }
```

You can get a lot fancier, pass parameters to the handler and all that.

Comment: here is msft reference to help you get it going.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events

Comment: Consider changing `MusicStarting?.Invoke`  to `MusicStarting?.BeginInvoke` because so as to avoid thread dead-lock in GUI apps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips. I'm sort of a "script kiddie" when it comes to coding, I know a little bit of C# but I use it to cobble together little applications for projects I do and it's always a bit janky lol. It's on a UI thread which I now realize is my main issue. Unfortunately in regards to that, my larger issue is I don't know how to make other threads. `MusicStarting += handleMusicStaring;` causes errors because it's outside of the `handleMusicStaring` void. Visual studio doesn't recognize MusicStarting at all either, which I don't understand. What should I do?

Comment: I gave the msft reference a look, I'm missing a whole lot of background info so it's hard to decipher for me but I get the jest of everything. I'm just unsure how to implement it properly (outside of your examples)

Comment: Did you see my comment regarding `MusicStarting += handleMusicStaring;`

Comment: maybe post a new question and show your code. Sounds like a scoping issue